# Patches, are they cumulative?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, cumulative-update, patching

I am several patches behind on my SharePoint 2016 installation. Should I install the latest feature pack then roll in the patches thereafter or should I roll all patches in, one at a time?

A related Q/A is here, but it doesn't quite answer my question:
[Cumulative Updates: Are they discrete?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35134/cumulative-updates-are-they-discrete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it include all previous updates since RTM version.

> The product group released the January 2018 Cumulative Update for
>   SharePoint Server 2016 product family. This CU also includes Feature
>   Pack 1 which was released with December 2016 CU and Feature Pack 2
>   which was released with September 2017 CU.

This one is latest CU released for SharePoint 2016: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/01/09/january-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/

But you have to apply both patches as mentioned in the article.

> Important: It is required to install both fixes to fully patch a
>   SharePoint server as each SharePoint installation comes with a
>   language independent component and a language dependent component. If
>   additional language packs are added later (only) the language
>   dependent fix has to be applied again.

Answer (score 1):

All SharePoint 2016 patches are cumulative. You must also apply both the sts-x-none and wssmui patch. There are 2 patches per month.